# Adding everything but the nth element to another arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, lisp, logic

For my project we have to manipulate certain LISP phrasing using Java. One of the tasks is given:

```
'((4A)(1B)(2C)(2A)(1D)(4E)2)
```

The number at the end is the "n". The task is to delete every nth element from the expression. For example, the expression above would evaluate to:

```
′((4A)(2C)(1D)2)
```

My approach right now is adding all the elements that aren't at the nth index to another array. My error is that it adds every single element to the new array leaving both elements identical.

My code:

```
    String input4=inData.nextLine();
    length=input4.length();
    String nString=input4.substring(length-2,length-1);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(nString);
    count=n;
    String delete1=input4.replace("'(","");
    String delete2=delete1.replace("(","");
    final1=delete2.replace(")","");
    length=final1.length();


    for (int i=1;i<length;i++)
    {
         part=final1.substring(i-1,i);
         list.add(part);

    }    

    for(int i=0;i<=list.size();i++)
    {

        if(!(i%n==0))
        {
            delete.add(list.get(i-1));
            delete.add(list.get(i));

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
    System.out.print("\n"+list);
```

Comment: Perhaps play around with your incrementors to jump ahead two at a time since the (num-char) is a 2-group. You would also have to double your modulo to compensate.

Comment: My issue is the each letter goes with one number. So if the nth element is 2 that I means i have to ignore 2 indexes. If nth element was 3, I'd have to ignore 3 indexes. I'm trying to figure out the correct logic for that but I having trouble @AlexPopov

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem (although not directly addressing your issue in your solution) is to use a Regex Pattern, as these work nicely for this sort of thing, especially if this code does not have to adapt much to different input strings. I find if something like this is possible, it is easier than trying to directly manipulate Strings, although these Patterns (and Regexs in general) are slow.

```
// Same as you had before
String input4="'((4A)(1B)(2C)(2A)(1D)(4E)2)";
int length=input4.length();
String nString=input4.substring(length-2,length-1);
int n = Integer.parseInt(nString);
int count=n;

// Match (..)
// This could be adapted to catch ( ) with anything in it other than another
// set of parentheses.
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(.{2}\\)").matcher(input4);

// Initialize with the start of the resulting string.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("'(");
int i = 0;
while (m.find())
{
  // If we are not at an index to skip, then append this group
  if (++i % count != 0)
  {
    sb.append(m.group());
  }
}

// Add the end, which is the count and the ending parentheses.
sb.append(count).append(")");

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Some example input/output:

```
'((4A)(1B)(2C)(2A)(1D)(4E)2)
'((4A)(2C)(1D)2)

'((4A)(1B)(2C)(2A)(1D)(4E)3)
'((4A)(1B)(2A)(1D)3)
```

Comment: do you have an alogorithm for that because I don't know/can't use that advanced level coding yet, but I could maybe translate it into something for more basic java

Comment: Are you required to use lists during this exercise? I have some advice, but it hinges on whether you are required to use lists.